# Suitable "h" parameter for the Kernel UD() function in R other than "href" to encompass all spatial points in the data

Tags: parameters, kernel-density

[Sample image of data used in this script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk887.png)#

Here is my R-script that results in the attached output for 50 and 95% occupancy contours.

```
library(sp)  
library(adehabitatHR)  
library(raster)  
library(ggplot2)
```

#read in a .csv which contains lat and long for your data points

```
Bat1 <- read.csv("D:/Bats/Bat1.csv", header = TRUE)
```

#create spatial points object

```
datapoints<-SpatialPoints(cbind(Bat1$Lat, Bat1$Lon))   

kud <- kernelUD(datapoints, h= "href", grid = 3000, extent = 5.0) 

image(kud)

hr50<-getverticeshr(kud, percent= 50, unout = "m2") 

hr95<-getverticeshr(kud, percent= 95, unout = "m2")
```

## set coordinates and write to shapefile which can be projected in ArcGIS

```
WGScoor1<- hr50
proj4string(WGScoor1)<- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellips=WGS84")
raster::shapefile(WGScoor1, "D:/Bats/Bat1HR_50_new.shp")

WGScoor2<- hr95
proj4string(WGScoor2)<- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellips=WGS84")
raster::shapefile(WGScoor2, "D:/Bats/Bat1HR_95_new.shp")
```

I am noticing how much ever I tweak the "grid", "extent" and "h" values, it does not encompass most of the spatial points. I found the smoothing parameter "h" is the one to manipulate but giving it either "LSCV" or number did not help.

What else could I try?
[50 and 95% contours resulting
shapefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQTxb.png)